# How to serialize a Date using AVRO in Java

Tags: java, datetime, serialization, avro

I'm actually trying to serialize objects containing dates with Avro, and the deserialized date doesn't match the expected value (tested with avro 1.7.2 and 1.7.1). Here's the class I'm serializing :

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Dummy {
    private Date date;
    private SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss.SSS");

    public Dummy() {
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return df.format(date);
    }
}
```

The code used to serialize / deserialize :

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;

import org.apache.avro.Schema;
import org.apache.avro.io.DatumReader;
import org.apache.avro.io.DatumWriter;
import org.apache.avro.io.Decoder;
import org.apache.avro.io.DecoderFactory;
import org.apache.avro.io.Encoder;
import org.apache.avro.io.EncoderFactory;
import org.apache.avro.reflect.ReflectData;
import org.apache.avro.reflect.ReflectDatumReader;
import org.apache.avro.reflect.ReflectDatumWriter;

public class AvroSerialization {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dummy expected = new Dummy();
        expected.setDate(new Date());
        System.out.println("EXPECTED: " + expected);
        Schema schema = ReflectData.get().getSchema(Dummy.class);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Encoder encoder = EncoderFactory.get().binaryEncoder(baos, null);
        DatumWriter<Dummy> writer = new ReflectDatumWriter<Dummy>(schema);
        try {
            writer.write(expected, encoder);
            encoder.flush();
            Decoder decoder = DecoderFactory.get().binaryDecoder(baos.toByteArray(), null);
            DatumReader<Dummy> reader = new ReflectDatumReader<Dummy>(schema);
            Dummy actual = reader.read(null, decoder);
            System.out.println("ACTUAL: " + actual);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("IOException: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

And the output :

```
EXPECTED: 06/11/2012 05:43:29.188
ACTUAL: 06/11/2012 05:43:29.387
```

Is it related to a known bug, or is it related to the way I'm serializing the object ?

Comment: I know I'm not answering your question, but I *wouldn't* use a static SimpleDateFormat. It's not a thread-safe class and consequently will give you unreliable results in a threaded environment

Comment: Thank you for the comment, this is actually not a production code, but only a test class I developed in order to expose my problem. Anyway you're right, so I removed the static modifier ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think AVRO doesn't serialize date at this point.
What I would do is to wrap it in another class and store at as a long (date.gettime()) while avro folks 
add [this feature](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-739).
And the reason that you see different Date values is that every time that you (and avro) create
a Date object, it initializes the Date with the current System time.

Comment: Thank you amas, it looks like Date are actually not supported as stated in your answer, and that the Date is actually initialized with the current System time.

Answer (score 33):

Avro 1.8 now has a date "logicalType", which annotates int. For example:

```
{"name": "date", "type": "int", "logicalType": "date"}
```

Quoting the spec:

> A date logical type annotates an Avro int, where the int stores the
> number of days from the unix epoch, 1 January 1970 (ISO calendar).

Comment: Why int and not long?

Comment: @AlessandroDionisi the spec calls for date because this particular type is the number of DAYS since the epoch. There is another logicalType "timestamp-millis" for the more common number of milliseconds and it is a long.

Comment: That's a con of AVRO, because after deserialisation, if you have your date in the JSON, it would appear as-
{
   date: 2020-08-10
}

whereas it is illegal in JSON to store date with hyphens without quotes.

Expected value would be - {date: "2020-08-10"} which means the type should be string,not int.

Comment: Who uses number of days after unix epoch? Why not millis as default?

Comment: @ama Because you're storing a _date_, not a datetime. If you use number of millis from epoch, you have 86,400,000 values that lie within each day. i.e. your representation of the date is not unique. It's also wasteful - if you record the number of millis, you can hold a far smaller date range before you have to use longs for storage.

Answer (score 1):

Issue Resolved at my end. I was also facing the same issue with serialisation of date field. Though Avro takes Date type as int. However once you declare it in this way

`{ "name": "DateEffective", "type": [ "null", { "type": "int", "logicalType": "date" } ],`

and **run avrogen -s** command than it makes C#/Java model class with date field.