# Defining Avro schema in Java, how do I handle timestamps or date values?

Tags: java, avro, apache-beam

I have a beam pipeline that takes json data, parses it, then writes it as parquet files to a GCS bucket. I dont know how to handle dates and timestamps when defining the Avro schema in Java. It doesn't give the option for Dates or similar. Only primitives. Right now everything works but my date stays as a string. Does anyone have any suggestions for defining dates/timestamps in an Avro schema object and also the Java objects to pass it in as?

```
static final Schema SCHEMA = SchemaBuilder.record("Record")
.namespace("com.foo").fields().requiredString("val1")
.requiredString("val2").requiredString("timestamp").endRecord();
```

Sample timestamp:

```
String timestamp = "2018-12-06T21:22:35.700Z";
```

Comment: it is OK to store date timestamp in String, then you can parse it depending on you thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

There is no single answer here. It depends on specifics of your use case.

You are receiving them as strings in the first place, so as @BSeitkazin mentioned it may be perfectly reasonable to keep them in strings until you actually need them as dates/timestamps.

Or you could store [millis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13255589/how-to-serialize-a-date-using-avro-in-java), or any other convenient for you way.

And looking at Avro, Dates seem to be [supported there since 1.8.0](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.0/spec.html#Date) (current Beam SDK [depends on 1.8.2](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/buildSrc/src/main/groovy/org/apache/beam/gradle/BeamModulePlugin.groovy#L356)).

Comment: I can keep it as a string, which is my current state and it works, but it would be ideal to store it as a date so that I can copy the parquet into a Redshift date column rather than having to copy into a string column and cast to a date. I'm not seeing a way to define a date specifically using the SchemaBuilder object in Java. It seems like others have converted date to long, then store the long in the schema, later converting back to a date. This works but is essentially the same as storing as a string then converting in Redshift. Thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried using the Avro 1.8.0+ date/time types?