# Apache Beam: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1/31/2021"

Tags: java, apache-beam, avro

I want to read the below CSV file and read the date column.
CSV File:

| ID | date | balance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 31/01/2021 | 100 |
| 02 | 28/02/2021 | 200 |
| 01 | 31/05/2021 | 500 |
| 02 | 30/06/2021 | 600 |

Schema file :

```
{
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "Entry",
  "namespace" : "transform",
  "fields" : [  {
    "name" : "ID",
    "type" : [ "string", "null" ]
  }, {
    "name" : "date",
    "type" : [ "int", "null" ],
    "logicalType": "date"
    
  }, {
    "name" : "balance",
    "type" : [ "double", "null" ]
  } ]
}
```

code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    
    final File schemaFile = new File("src/main/resources/schema_ie_date.avsc");

    File csvFile = new File("src/main/resources/CustomerRequestIE.csv");

    Schema schema = new Schema.Parser().parse(schemaFile);

    Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create();

    // Reading schema
    org.apache.beam.sdk.schemas.Schema beamSchema = AvroUtils.toBeamSchema(schema);

    final PCollectionTuple tuples = pipeline

            // Reading csv input
            .apply("1", FileIO.match().filepattern(csvFile.getAbsolutePath()))

            // Reading files that matches conditions //PRashanth needs to be looked at
            .apply("2", FileIO.readMatches())

            // Reading schema and validating with schema and converts to row and returns
            // valid and invalid list
            .apply("3", ParDo.of(new FileReader(beamSchema)).withOutputTags(FileReader.validTag(),
                    TupleTagList.of(invalidTag())));

    // Fetching only valid rows

    final PCollection<Row> rows = tuples.get(FileReader.validTag()).setCoder(RowCoder.of(beamSchema));

    

}
```

When I try to run the code, it throws number format exception.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1/31/2021"
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13255589/how-to-serialize-a-date-using-avro-in-java

Answer (score 0):

Change the **date** schema type from **int** to **string**:

```
{
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "Entry",
  "namespace" : "transform",
  "fields" : [  {
    "name" : "ID",
    "type" : [ "string", "null" ]
  }, {
    "name" : "date",
    "type" : [ "string", "null" ],
    "logicalType": "date"
    
  }, {
    "name" : "balance",
    "type" : [ "double", "null" ]
  } ]
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Can you explain where you found the solution? Because I can't find this in documentation.

Comment: @danilo For the date it was being read as an 'int', and hence when processing it was throwing date Number format exception. But when I changed the type from 'int' to 'string' it was able to process successfully.